# Could Delegated Authentication be considered SP or IdP initiated SSO?

Tags: single-sign-on, saml, delegated-authentication

I understand that "Delegated Authentication" (DA) is a unique SSO option specific to the SFDC platform.

Can we think about DA as non-SAML SP or IdP initiated SSO?

Could DA ever be considered "Service Provider" (SP) or "Identify Provider" (IdP) initiated SSO, or do these terms imply SAML/Federated SSO only?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SP and IdP are really SAML-based definitions, but if you wanted to give such a definition to DA, it would be a SP SSO; the user starts from Salesforce, the SP, and presents their credentials through DA to the IdP to complete the login process. However, generally speaking, you wouldn't call DA SAML (which is the Security Assertion Markup Language, a specific protocol for SSO technology that uses certificates and XML to pass authentication tokens).

Comment: thanks, that makes sense. SP only, never IdP. Understood, DA and SAML assertions are entirely different animals.